# Timezones in Civi Event

Tags: civievent

Our event has become internationalized. We had someone in India (GMT+5.5) attempt to register for our Event, hosted on a server in PST, with an end time of 11:59PM. They attempted to register on the PST timeline, at 4PM PST, but it said registration had ended. What's going on ?

Note: Timezones boggle my simple mind, thanks in advance for understanding.

Comment: Have a read of https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2122

Comment: Yes, I just need an ELI5 due to being stressed out. Is there any fix I can implement right now?